# CSS Flexbox Image Shrink

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am working on a website and have a `CSS` `flexbox` question. Basically, I have a `div` of a fixed height and width. Inside the `div`, I need to have a title area, content area, and footer area (in that order, top to bottom). The title and footer area must always be tall enough to render their contents (usually one line of text). The content area must shrink such that the three areas fit into their parent `div`, vertically (and horizontally).

The problem is that the content area consists of a picture that must maintain aspect ratio when the content area shrinks to fit vertically.

My basic methodology (that does not work): use CSS `flex` on the parent `div`. Make the title area and footer area have `flex-shrink` be 0 (thus they fit their contents). Then, make the `flex-shrink` of the content area and the image inside of it be 1 (to [theoretically] make all three areas fit, but this does not work, as evidenced by the JSFiddle).

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="title-container"> <!-- should not shrink -->
         <h1>Title</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="picture-container"> <!--should shrink to fit vertically and horizontally -->
        <img src="http://i.imgur.com/D08iV30.jpg"> <!-- should fit inside picture-container and maintain aspect ratio -->
    </div>
    <div class="button-container"> <!-- should not shrink -->
        <span>button</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.container {
    border: 1px solid black;
    height: 300px;
    width: 300px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}
.title-container {
    flex-shrink: 0;
}
.button-container {
    flex-shrink: 0;
}
.picture-container {
    flex-shrink: 1;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}
.picture-container img {
    flex-shrink: 1;
}
```

**JSFiddle demonstrating problem:**[here](http://jsfiddle.net/phws3g4p/)

The solution does not have to use `flexbox`. The only requirements are that the title and button areas do not shrink, the content area shrinks such that all three areas fit both vertically and horizontally in the `container`, and the image in the content area fits in the content area preserves aspect ratio.

Thanks in advance for any assistance.

Comment: To be honest I think you've painted yourself into a corner there...the element sizing is simple enough, as you've found, but the aspect ratio requirement is probably  a step to much.

Comment: @Paulie_D Please pardon my ignorance, but since it's an image don't I have to preserve aspect ratio? I think it might look pretty weird if the image were crushed or stretched. It seems like this should be possible and I'm just missing something (but I could be wrong)

Comment: Oh...you mean like this - http://jsfiddle.net/phws3g4p/2/

Comment: @Paulie_D Unfortunately, that doesn't appear to work for certain sizes of the parent container div. For example, if you change the width of the container div in the JSFiddle to 700px, the image no longer vertically fits in the container div (and the content and button area divs don't vertically fit either). The solution should work for portrait, landscape, and square container div sizes.

But yes, that JSFiddle result is what I wanted for that size of container div ... it should work for all container div sizes though

Comment: Like I said...paint/corner.

Comment: @Paulie_D I appreciate the fact that I may be painting myself into a corner. I thought that perhaps this type of thing could be accomplished (I am using it for a modal dialog that has to work on a variety of screen sizes). I do appreciate your input but hopefully someone knows how to satisfy the conditions, with any luck

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If instead of `img` you use `background-image` for `div.picture-container`, you can use [`cover` or `contain`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-size) on the background to maintain aspect ratio ([fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5vn4b28k/)):

**HTML:**

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="title-container">
         <h1>Title</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="picture-container" style="background-image: url(http://i.imgur.com/D08iV30.jpg)">
    </div>
    <div class="button-container">
        <span>button</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.container {
    border: 1px solid black;
    height: 300px;
    width: 300px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}
.title-container {
    flex-shrink: 0;
}
.button-container {
    flex-shrink: 0;
}
.picture-container {
    flex: 1;
    background-size: cover; /** you can use contain if you want to prevent image cropping **/
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much for the suggestion! Just integrated it into what I'm building and it appears to work like a charm. Marked as the accepted answer.

Comment: Welcome. I hate corners :-P